# I am getting errors here error is ('str' object is not callable)

Tags: python

```
print("Lets play a game")
print("You have to operte on some numbers")

print("Are you ready? , type yes or no ")

input = input().lower()

if input == "yes":
    print("Ok now type your name and age (comma separated)")
    name = input()
    age = int(input())
    if "\"" in name or ">" in name :
        print("Use only alphanumeric characters")
    else:
        pass
    if age <= 10 :
        print("You cant play this game")
```

I keep on getting this error `'str' object is not callable` in line 10.

Comment: `input = input()` - you're shadowing the function. Don't use one name for two things.

Comment: When you use `input = input().lower()`, you overwrite the built-in name for the `input` function. This means that, before that line is run, `input` was a built-in function, and after that, it's a string. Later on, when you try to run `input()` again, this error is thrown, Change your variable name (e.g. `input_val = input().lower()` )

Comment: ok Now i understand Thanks:)

Comment: Well somebody knows how to make my "age" variable an integer? like in name,age = input().split(",") ?

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing the built-in `input()` function with the `input` variable, so the second time you call `input()` it tries to 'call' the string variable.

You will have to work out what to do when the user doesn't input what you expect, but here's a skeleton for what the code could look like:

```
print("Let's play a game")
print("You have to operate on some numbers")
text = input("Are you ready (yes/no)?").lower()

if text == "yes":
    text = input("Enter your name and age (comma separated):")
    fields = text.split(",")
    if len(fields) != 2:
        # Handle case of bad user input format

    name = fields[0].trim()
    if not all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in name):
        # Handle case of bad entered name
    try:
        age = int(fields[1])
    except ValueError:
        # Handle case of bad entered age

    if age <= 10:
        print("You cannot play this game")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are getting derives from the name of the variable, "input". If you change it, "ready" in my example, you will avoid the error.

I would also recommend to include functions to check the inputs and use the while loop, so the program does not finish if there is an unexpected input.

Please, see my code below:

```
def check_predefined_input(variable, values, input_question, error_message, check = False):
    variable = str(input(input_question))
    try:
        if(variable.lower() in values):
            check = True
        else:
            raise Exception ("You have inserted an invalid option.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR: ", e)
        print(error_message, "\n")
        check = False
    return variable, check

def check_string_input(variable, input_question, error_message, check = False):
    variable = input(input_question)
    if "\"" in variable or ">" in variable:
        print("ERROR: ", error_message, "\n")
        check = False
    else:
        check = True
    return variable, check

def check_int_input(variable, input_question, error_message, check = False):
    try:
        variable = int(input(input_question))
        check = True
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("ERROR: ", ve)
        print(error_message, "\n")
        variable = 0
        check = False
    return variable, check

print("Lets play a game")
print("You have to operate on some numbers")

ready_values = ["yes", "no"]
ready = ''
ready_input_question = "Are you ready? , type yes or no "
ready_error_message =  "\tMake sure your answer is yes or not."
ready_check = False
while not ready_check:
    ready, ready_check = check_predefined_input(ready, ready_values, ready_input_question, ready_error_message, ready_check)


if ready == "yes":
    name = ""
    name_check = False
    name_input_question = "Ok now type your name: "
    name_error_message = "Use only alphanumeric characters"
    while not name_check:
        name, name_check = check_string_input(name, name_input_question, name_error_message, name_check)

    age = 0
    age_check = False
    age_input_question = 'Please, ' + name + ', insert your age: '
    age_error_message =  '\tMake sure you insert your age.\n\tDo not insert letters.'
    while not age_check:
        age, age_check= check_int_input(age, age_input_question, age_error_message)

    if age <= 10 :
        print("You cannot play this game")
    else:
        print("You are ready to play")
```